# How can i connnect `IConsumeMessageObserver` to the consumer, in the context of DI, using `AddMediator()` extension method, in MassTransit?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, masstransit, mediator

I was faced with one diffucult, I havent idea how to add `IConsumeMessageObserver` entity in DI context, using `AddMediator()` extension method. In that section (https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/observers.html#received-messages), only shows, how do it manually.

I tried to resolve `IMediator` after `AddMediator()` call, like this:

```
private static void BindInMemoryBroker ( IServiceCollection services )
        {
            services.AddMediator ( configuration =>
              {
                  AddInMemoryAddOnBroker ( configuration );
              } );

            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider ();

            var mediator = serviceProvider.GetService<IMediator> ();

            var observer1 = serviceProvider.GetService<MailingObserver<RetrieveAddOnDownloadLinkContract>> ();

            var observer2 = serviceProvider.GetService<IncrementAddOnDownloadCounterObserver<RetrieveAddOnDownloadLinkContract>> ();

            mediator.ConnectConsumeMessageObserver ( observer1 );

            mediator.ConnectConsumeMessageObserver ( observer2 );
        }

        private static void AddInMemoryAddOnBroker ( IServiceCollectionMediatorConfigurator configuration )
        {
            AddInMemoryConsumers ( configuration );

            AddInMemoryContracts ( configuration );
        }

        private static void AddInMemoryConsumers ( IServiceCollectionMediatorConfigurator configuration )
        {

            configuration.AddConsumer<RetrieveAddOnDownloadLinkConsumer> ();

        }

        private static void AddInMemoryContracts ( IServiceCollectionMediatorConfigurator configuration )
        {
            configuration.AddRequestClient<RetrieveAddOnDownloadLinkContract> ();
        }
```

But it didn't work, pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of consume observers, one is delivered all message types (`IConsumeObserver`) and the other is only delivered a single message type (`IConsumeMessageObserver`). The latter can only be connected to an `IBus` or `IMediator`, therefore it cannot be configuring within either the `AddMediator` or the `AddMassTransit` configuration.

You can add an `IConsumeObserver` and use pattern matching to select only the message types you need as an alternative.